# Android emulator uses wrong layout resources?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Android emulator uses wrong layout resources ,i'm having a two layout hdpi, mdpi but in emulator get a wrong one why ....
I added in my manifest file  ,

```
     <supports-screens
     android:anyDensity="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
 />
```

Comment: Can you explain why you are saying Android emulator is using wrong resources or what are expecting ?

Comment: i set the emulator for hdpi(480*800) but it get that mdpi

Answer (score 1):

In andorid drawable resources usage is depends on ppi.

Please refer the link http://developer.vodafone.com/image-and-graphics-tips-android/

You have to change the emulator ppi values and try your's. Thanks...